# What SciFi series(?) of books features humans time traveling into prehistory where an alien race is already in residence?

Tags: story-identification, aliens, time-travel, prehistoric

There is no return for the humans. I seem to remember that the humans and aliens find a way to get on, or I could be wrong. A small house in the Camargue of France is the link between the present and the past.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is the [Saga of the Pliocene Exile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saga_of_Pliocene_Exile) by Julian May

> The Saga of Pliocene Exile (known as the Saga of the Exiles in some
>   markets) is a narrative surrounding the adventures of a group of late
>   21st and early 22nd century misfits/outcasts who travel through a
>   one-way time-gate to Earth's Pliocene epoch, in the hopes of finding a
>   simple utopia where they can finally fit in.
>
> However, the reality is far removed from the dream. The time-travelers
>   arrive to discover the Pliocene is already inhabited by a dimorphic
>   race of aliens ('exotics'), the Tanu and the Firvulag. The exotics,
>   who have fled their home galaxy because of religious persecution, are
>   marooned on Pliocene Earth as well.